# Travis issues with .yml and build times

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I have recently started using Travis and I have a couple of issues with it. Firstly my `.travis.yml` file seems to be incorrect. I have set it up to use with FTP following [these instructions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/). My `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
language: generic
notifications:
 slack:
  secure: 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

env:
 global:
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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

after_success:
  "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_ADDRESS/var/www/test"
```

When using the [.travis.yml validation tool](https://lint.travis-ci.org/) it validates correctly but after my build passes successfully the files are not uploaded onto the server. The `FTP_USER` account is not a sudouser so that might affect something but is there something wrong with my `.yml` file anywhere?

My second issue is that my build times are taking quite a long time, at least I think. After committing something to my repo that is only 9MB large, it takes about 1-2 minutes to build, I would expect it to be finished almost instantly. Since my repo is almost entirely in HTML/CSS with some PHP would I benefit from changing my language to PHP or should I just stay with generic?

Comment: For the second question, you could change it to specific and observe the build times youself. ;)

Comment: `FTP_USER` and `FTP_PASSWORD` are the environment variables, right? You set those manually in the Travis UI? Did you try putting `sudo` before `curl` command? How did you encrypt those?

Comment: @Azeem I encrypted the variables using the travis encrypt command, I used 'travis encrypt FTP_USER=<username> --add' and the same for the password. I have not tried putting sudo before curl no

Comment: Right. And, after that encryption, you did put these variables in Travis CI's UI also, right?

Comment: @Azeem um no? I didnt realise you had to

Comment: Well, you encrypted the variables along with the values and got that encrypted pair. Technically, anyone can copy that and use that. So, from the point of security, it's you who know that environment variable so you should be able to do this.

Comment: Another thing is that you need to use `-r <user>/<repo>` with your encrypt command. Something like this: `$ travis encrypt -r harry/mysite ENV_UN=username --add`. So that it would be bound to your repo only. For starters, you can simply put those variables in your `.travis.yml` file to validate that it works without encryption.

Comment: Take a look at this for encryption: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/

Comment: I ran the command in my project repo though... so surely I dont need to use the `-r <user>/<repo>` command? I am still confused about what you are saying with regards to the variables in the Travis UI

Comment: Oh, that's right. Running it in your repo folder should work for your repo. Did you check it without encryption?

Comment: No but I dont really want to as people will be able to see the login info..

Comment: Take a look at this for setting env vars: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings

Comment: Oh so with that I just put in FTP_USER and FTP_PASSWORD into the name and then the respective values into the value box rather than having to do it in the `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Yup. That's correct.

Comment: @Azeem, I now seem to get this error `curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_ADDRESS/var/www/test
curl: Can't open 'uploadfilename'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information` Any ideas?

Comment: What is `uploadfilename` here? Seems like a hard-coded. Does it represent anything that's in your repo?

Comment: I am being quite stupid I think, I just copied and pasted from [this guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/) and I thought uploadfilename was just an array created by Travis

Comment: :) You need to provide your files that you need to upload to the server.

Comment: How can I do this without having to change the command every time?

Comment: What do you want to upload? I guess it's your entire repo, right?

Comment: Well it will be different files depending on what's changed, I could upload my whole repo every time but wouldn't that just be a bit of a waste of bandwidth?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163133/discussion-between-azeem-and-harry-cameron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your `.travis.yml` file looks fine.

Here are some things that you can try:

Take a look at this: [Defining public variables in .travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-public-variables-in-.travis.yml)
Here, there's no `global` under `env`. I don't think it's an issue but you may want to test it out as well. (It's a try but I'm pretty sure it isn't the issue!)

I believe you are using this command for encrypting environment variables:

```
[your-repo-dir] $ travis encrypt FTP_UN=username --add
[your-repo-dir] $ travis encrypt FTP_PW=password --add
```

Instead of doing this, you can try something like this:

```
[your-repo-dir] $ travis encrypt --add
// You'll be prompted for input and then press CTRL+D
// Simply, paste or type here the string and press CTRL+D
// String: FTP_UN=username and FTP_PW=password
```

Alternatively, you can set environment variables from Travis CI UI. It should work!
Follow this: [Defining Variables in Repository Settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings)

Another important thing is that you need to upload your changed files from your repo to the server. Right now, your `curl` command would work only for one file i.e. `uploadfilename`. You would need some kind of bash to run into `after_success` section to do this for you.
Take a look at this: [Use Travis CI to Update Your Website using FTP and Git](http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/use-travis-ci-to-update-your-website-using-ftp-and-git.html)
Do read the comments for this post. There's some issue of file permission that you need to take care in `before_install` section.

If you are using some kind of build and deploy tool then it should do the heavy lifting for you instead of doing it all by yourself.

Hope that helps!